# Postfix rewrite header issue

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtp-headers

I currently relay all my cPanel (exim) outbound emails through my Postfix server. However, postfix seems to remove some important part in the header that exim added before sending to relay. As example, exim add in the headers the path of the PHP script that send the email, or the unix user ID of the sender.

Anyone know how to stop postfix relay from removing those important header part ?

Here is an example of headers part that is removed by the postfix relay :

```
X-PHP-Script: www.website.com/user/email/index.php for 1.1.1.1
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include 
  it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server.website.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - website.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [99 32003] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - www.website.com
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL 
X-Source-Dir: website.com:/public_html/website/email
```

Thanks,

Karl

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the headers look like before they get to postfix and after postfix has modified them?

Comment: @larsks I added them in the original post, thanks.

Comment: After doing a tcpdump on the source server, it seems that exim/cpanel doesn't add all those X-AntiAbuse when sending at the relay. So the issue come from exim and not the postfix relay.

Answer (score 1):

I've finaly find the problem. If anyone have the same problem with cPanel, simply add headers_add = "${perl{mailtrapheaders}}" in the routers configuration of exim.conf